# How to document my page object

Tags: page-objects, documentation

What are some efficient and non-tedious ways to document my page objects?

What I first did was take screen shots of my screen and label each page object to its corresponding web element but this turned out to be a night mare and now I am wondering of more convenient ways to document my page objects so that others can digest which methods or page elements go where with little effort.

---

I use selenium and page object model to run my tests.

Answer (score 3):

I recommend avoiding external documentation because no one wants to maintain it.  Instead, use comments in your code and useful names for your classes and methods.  And ask someone to review some of your code specifically with those considerations in mind.

Comment: You are spot on about external documentation - on how no one wants to maintain it. I am the only one that maintains it. And yup we do use comments in our code and useful names. Just wondering if there were more useful resources I could use.

Answer (score 0):

Even i feel external documentation is a burden, better way will be distributing page elements meaningfully in into different smaller classes with comments and apt names.